# Getting Current Login in User name using Angular js

Tags: angularjs, jsp, waffle

I have used Waffle to get the Current Logged in User using Jsp and Tomcat.
But how do i replicate the Same using Angularjs .

I have used the Demo code in Git for waffle https://dblock.github.com/waffle/

Please help as i am confused of how to get the Angular app to Call the jsp and fetch username back to the Angular app .

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion best way to check for user is using AngularJS http interceptor.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return {
            'request': function(response) {

            },
            'response': function (response) {

                // TODO Create check for user authentication. With every request send "headers"
                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function (reject) {

                // Forbidden
                if(reject.status == 403) {
                    console.log('This page is forbidden.');
                    window.location = '/';
                // Unauthorized
                } else if(reject.status == 401) {
                    console.log("You're not authorized to view this page.");
                    window.location = '/';
                }

                return $q.reject(reject);
            }
        };
    });
```

Write a function in 'response' to check http headers for user or something similar. [Interceptors in AngularJS](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

This interceptor will run with every call you make to Database and if error is returned you can also handle this there.

Comment: i want the current logged in username ?